# Update records of a column with the data of another table

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update all the records from 'column1' of 'table1' with the data from 'column2' of 'table2'. This is my code:

```
UPDATE table1 SET column1 = (SELECT column2 FROM table2);
```

Unfortunately, I get this message:

> Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you run `SELECT column2 FROM table2` by itself, what do you get? -- more than one row!   Search for "how can i do an update statement with join in sql"     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql

Comment: Thanks Wruckie. I solved my problem following the instructions of your link.